# Why are the Hairs of the particle settings under my icing?

Tags: particles

[image: Blederguru tutorial]Hey Guys, im just about to do an Youtube tutorial from Blenderguru. The Tutorial is about placing Random Particles on the Icing of an Donut. Somehow when I click on the Particlesettings of the Icing and select Hair, the hairs are not like in the Tutorial they are just under the Icing. I dont know what to do, i would be very gratefull for some help.

Comment: Hi :). Could be just flipped normals https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165081/78972

Comment: yes, have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/191243/107598, similar question

Comment: Thank you that was a big help for me